# Elastic search _doc with sort

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, kibana

I am paginating elastic search data using search_after with sort using ***_uid***. Sorting over huge amount of data leads to circuit breaker exception, as the field data size limit is exceeded. A possible solution provided by elastic search for sorting the large dataset is with ***_doc***
(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-request-sort.html) 
This helps in getting the response quickly without failing with circuit breaker exception. However I am concerned about the unique value which is being used in search_after to get the next set of records as this value will be used as a cursor to get the next records. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-request-scroll.html

To understand what does the _doc value represent I was going through the documentation but there is no description added.

In my data I see more than few records with same _doc value. these documents with same _doc value has different _ids meaning they are two different records. Can anyone help me in understanding what does this value represents. Can I used it in search_after? I am using elastic version 5.4

Comment: From the documentation, "`_doc` to sort by index order". Not sure how two documents can have equal `_doc`, given that always a document will be inserted either before another, or after.

Comment: You are right. _doc is internal document id created by elastic search but I am wondering why is not unique

Comment: _doc is the order in which the doc was indexed on the specific shard, so if your index has 30 shards, there can be 30 docs with the same _doc value, for example 30 docs with "0" _doc value, as they were the first doc on their respective shard